# How to populate one large dataframe with the contents of another without resorting to R for loop indexing?

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing

I have two large dataframes, A (~25,000 rows) and B (~275,000 rows), and I need to populate A with the contents of B. I'm new to R, but I've written in Python before where this sort of thing can be done reasonably quickly with for loops and indices in pandas. But since loops with dataframe indexing are painfully slow in R, my approach as written would take days to run. Anyone have any idea how I can accomplish the following more efficiently?

```
IDs <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
description1 <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
description2 <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
description3 <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)

descriptions <- c('description1','description3','description3','description1','description1','description2','description1','description3','description2','description2')
values <- c(100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000)

A <- data.frame(IDs,description1,description2,description3)
B <- data.frame(IDs,descriptions,values)

for (k in 1:nrow(B)){
  for (y in 1:nrow(A)){
    col_index <- which(names(A) == B[k,2])
    column_name <- names(A)[col_index]
    ID_A <- A[y,1]
    ID_B <- B[k,1]
    descriptionA <- A[y,4]
    descriptionB <- B[k,2]
    if ((ID_A == ID_B) && (descriptionB == column_name)){
      A[y,col_index] <- B[k,3]
    }
  }
}
```

Hopefully this is trivially easy and I'm being an idiot. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually just `reshape` the data by using `dcast` in the `reshape2` package:

```
dcast(B, IDs ~ descriptions)

   IDs description1 description2 description3
1    1          100           NA           NA
2    2           NA           NA          200
3    3           NA           NA          300
4    4          400           NA           NA
5    5          500           NA           NA
6    6           NA          600           NA
7    7          700           NA           NA
8    8           NA           NA          800
9    9           NA          900           NA
10  10           NA         1000           NA
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP has indicated that processing speed is crucial because of the problem size.

Now, `dcast` is available from the `reshape2` package as well as from the `data.table` package. The latter [claims:](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.10.4/topics/dcast.data.table)

> `dcast.data.table` is a much faster version of `reshape2::dcast`, but
>   for `data.table`s. More importantly, it's capable of handling very
>   large data quite efficiently in terms of memory usage in comparison to
>   `reshape2::dcast`.

So, I wondered which version would be faster for the given problem size of 25.000 rows in data.frame `A` (which is the number of unique `IDs`) and 275.000 rows in data.frame `B`.

#### Creating benchmark data

```
n_ID <- 25000L
n_rows_B <- 275000L
n_desc_per_ID <- round(n_rows_B / n_ID)
descriptions <- sprintf("d%02i", seq_len(2L * n_desc_per_ID))
# set.seed() is required for reproducible data
set.seed(123L)
B_DF <- data.frame(IDs = rep(1:n_ID, each = n_desc_per_ID),
                   d   = as.vector(replicate(n_ID, sample(descriptions, n_desc_per_ID))),
                   v   = rpois(n_rows_B, 50))
B_DT <- data.table::data.table(B_DF)
```

As there are 11 times as many rows in `B` as unique `IDs` in `A`, for each `IDs` 11 samples are randomly picked from 22 different `descriptions`. Note that the variable names have been abbreviated in order to save screen space in wide format later.

`B` looks as follows

> ```
>           IDs   d  v
>      1:     1 d07 43
>      2:     1 d17 36
>      3:     1 d09 49
>      4:     1 d21 52
>      5:     1 d19 50
>     ---             
> 274996: 25000 d09 47
> 274997: 25000 d18 46
> 274998: 25000 d17 47
> 274999: 25000 d14 64
> 275000: 25000 d02 57
> ```

#### Benchmarking

For benchmarking, the `microbenchmark` package is used:

```
bm <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  reshape2 = 
    res1 <- reshape2::dcast(B_DF, IDs ~ d, value.var = "v"),
  datatable = 
    res2 <- data.table::dcast(B_DT, IDs ~ d, value.var = "v"),
  times = 100L
)
bm
```

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
>   reshape2 69.57883 72.90287 84.61567 84.45119 86.10444 198.6079   100
>  datatable 34.66349 36.23196 39.80785 39.67117 40.37139 168.9877   100
> ```

For the given problem size `dcast.data.table` is indeed twice as fast as `reshape2::dcast`. However, the problem size is still small and the absolute run times are negligible. The difference becomes more obvious when increasing the problem size. For a problem size of 2.7 M rows in `B` the run times are 1.2 secs to 0.4 secs.